# Application Insights Behaviour with Azure Functions and WebAPI

Tags: azure, azure-functions, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-application-insights

This question is more on the logging to AI from Azure Functions and from the WebAPI. In WebAPI we need to provide the Instrumentation Key while initializing the Logger from the Startup.cs. But in functions, it's been taken Automatically and the logs are getting logged on to the AIs automatically. Why is the difference in behavior for logging data from different kind of applications on to the AI in Azure. I was trying to figure out the same and most of the people gave an answer which says the function contains the inbuilt logger and it is more of a serverless. I am not getting satisfied with this answer as WebAPI also runs in the context of the AppServices in Azure. It will be helpful if some one can throw some light on this issue.

Regards,
Ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer "the function contains the inbuilt logger and it is more of a serverless." is actually the answer.

The azure function has an extension [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights/3.0.14) running background which is used to read Instrumentation key and write logs to Application insights. So you just provide an Instrumentation key for function is ok. You can also find more via the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/tree/5d55eb1614c9146625c0179de9cdad530ea3ca17/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights).

But web api does not have such built-in extensions, we need to configure AI by ourselves.